# How to resize two layouts in a Qt widget?

Tags: qt

I have a **Qt Widget** which contains two scroll areas vertically. In these scroll areas, labels are dynamically  added and the count of labels always changes. Now I am trying to implement a feature where i can drag either the bottom border or top border of the second scroll area so that the view of the dragged border changes. Does anyone know how can this feature be achieved.
[image]

Comment: Change the vertical layout by a QSplitter, you can do this in Qt Designer

Comment: But Qt4.7.1 designer does not have QSplitter

Comment: Then you will have it done by code.

Comment: I recommend updating your version of Qt designer, at least in version 4.8.7 if I have verified that QSplitter exists.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Qt 4.7.1 does support, and your answer helped out. Thank you.